# Storing int values in an uint8_t array in code composer studio vs 5.4

Tags: embedded, printf

I have a string in a `uint8_t str[]` array and I am trying to store the positions of characters within the `str` in another variable called `uint8_t pos[]`. The code is written in Code Composer Studio vs 5.4

I tried using `sprintf()`, type casting as well as changing the type of `uint8_t pos[]` to `int pos[]` as well as `unsigned int pos[]`. None of these work.

The code breaks at the `sprintf` statement and comes to a halt by reaching an undefined memory location. When I run in assembly after reaching `sprintf` statement, it gives an error saying that a source code for *sprint.c* cannot be found in location.

[image]

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tm4c123gh6pm.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void initHw()
{
.
.
}

int main(void)
{
    // Initialize hardware
    initHw();
    char strRx[80];

    int count =0;
    int count_enter=0;
    uint8_t posStr[80];
    uint8_t typeStr[80];
    int pos=0;
    int len;
    unsigned int j=0, argCount=0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            putsUart0("Enter characters for the string\r\n");
        }
        if(count <= 80)
        {
            char c = getcUart0();
            if(c=='\b')
                if(count>0)
                    count--;
                else
                    break;

            if(c>=' ')
            {
                strRx[count]=c;
                count++;
            }
            if(count==80 || c==13)//'\r')
            {
                    count_enter++;
                    if(count_enter==1)  //count==80 before carriage return
                    {
                        len = count;
                        strRx[count]='\0';
                        while(count!=80)
                            strRx[count++]='\0';

                        count_enter=0;
                        putsUart0("\r\nEntered string is:\r\n");
                        putsUart0(strRx);
                        putsUart0("\r\n");
                    }

                    j=0;
                    //char a[10];
                    for(pos=0; pos!=len; pos++)// strRx[pos]!='\0'; pos++)
                    {
                        char a[80];
                        if((strRx[pos]>='A' && strRx[pos]<='Z') || (strRx[pos]>='a' && strRx[pos]<='z'))
                        {
                            typeStr[j]='a';
                            //posStr[j]=pos;
                            a[j]=pos;
                            sprintf(a,"%u",pos);    //source not found
                            //a[j]=pos;
                            //posStr[j]=sprintf("%c",a);
                            //posStr[j]=(uint8_t)a;//a;
                            while(strRx[pos]!='\0'&&((strRx[pos]>='A' && strRx[pos]<='Z') || (strRx[pos]>='a' && strRx[pos]<='z')))
                            {
                                pos++;
                            }
                            pos--;
                            j++;
                        }

                        else if(strRx[pos]>='0' && strRx[pos]<='9')
                        {
                            typeStr[j]='n';
                            a[j]=pos;
                            sprintf(a,"%u",pos);
                            //posStr[j]=pos;//a;
                            while(strRx[pos]!='\0'&&((strRx[pos]>='0' && strRx[pos]<='9')))
                            {
                                pos++;
                            }
                            pos--;
                            j++;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            while(strRx[pos]!='\0'&&((strRx[pos]<'A' && strRx[pos]>'Z') && (strRx[pos]<'a' && strRx[pos]>'z') && (strRx[pos+1]<'0' && strRx[pos+1]>'9')))
                                pos++;
                        }
                    }
                    argCount=j;
                    while(j!=80)
                    {
                        typeStr[j++]='\0';
                        posStr[j++]='\0';

                    }
                count = 0;
            }//if(count==80 || c==13)//'\r')
        }//if count<=80
    }//while(1)
}//main
```

Comment: Without [showing the _relevant_ code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clearer description of what happens vs. what's meant to happen, there's not much anyone can do but guess. By the sound of it though, if you're trying to create an array of indices, `sprintf` is _very much_ the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Code composer **for what processor??**  There have been IDE's by that name for a huge variety of processors, **including DSP's on which `char` is a 16-bit type** (which may or may not be specifically relevant, but shows how much has been left unsaid).

Comment: @Notlikethat Can you please suggest some alternatives?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It is an ARM Cortex M4F processor

Comment: sprintf() would produce a *textual representation* - is that what you want?  If so, why are you also assigning to the same array?  You may want to consider writing stubs for your input functions and testing the basic algorithm by building it instead for your development machine - when you aren't sure what you are trying to do in a piece of code, it's a lot harder to figure that out in an embedded context.  It's quite common for a source-level debugger to not have what it needs to display sources of library functions; most often you don't need to worry about those.

Answer (score 0):

The "unable to locate sprintf.c" error probably just means that the debugger cannot locate the source file, which means it cannot show the source code in the debugger window.  It's possible that you don't have the source code for sprintf.c and all you have is the precompiled library.  Or maybe you do have the source code and the debugger is simply looking in the wrong path.  If you have the source code then there may be a way to tell the debugger which path to find it.

But that is just a debugger display issue -- It is not what is causing your program to crash.  The problem may be in your code but you'd have to share your code for us to identify that.  Or the problem may be a couple other issues that can occur with the printf related routines.

1) printf routines can use a relatively large amount of stack space.  So check for a stack overflow and increase the stack size if necessary.

2) Some embedded libraries provide multiple implementations of the printf routines such as "small", "no-float", and "full".  The limited implementations use less code space but don't support all of the format specifiers.  So make sure the implementation of sprintf that you've linked with supports all the format specifiers that you're actually using.  Look through the project settings under linker or libraries for an option to select which version of printf is used.

Comment: I have included the code in the post. can you please explain how I can check for stack overflow. Also I have selected printf support in the library function assumptions as full. Thanks.

Comment: I've looked at the code and I don't understand what you're intending to do.  I'm skeptical whether sprintf is what you want to use.  If you're sure sprintf is what you want then see [tips for using printf](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Tips_for_using_printf) with CCS.

Comment: One way to check for a stack overflow is to pre-fill the stack with a pattern (such as 0xDEADBEEF).  (You could do this in the debugger, via a memory window for example, after loading and before running the code.)  Then run your code.  Then halt and make sure the pattern was not overwritten throughout the entire stack.  Where the pattern remains is the high-water-mark of the stack.  If the pattern has been completely overwritten then you overflowed the stack.